# Is "must will be willing" grammatically correct?

Tags: modal-verbs

*In the clip below, Zizek praises the revolutionary violence of the Robespierre and argues that true revolutionary must will be willing to become victim to revolutionary terror.*

Source: http://www.critical-theory.com/zizek-terror-awesome/

Is the phrase "must will be willing" grammatically OK? Does "will" function in that sentence as the main verb or auxiliary one that indicates future tense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is almost certainly a typing mistake. My guess is the author started to type something, and then changed it, and forgot to delete the word "will". They may have originally typed "[...] true revolutionary will be willing", without the "must", or they mistyped "will" instead of "be willing" and then did not delete it.

Also, "true revolutionary" should take an article. "**a** true revolutionary" is probably what was intended and is the normal construction. However, some artistic license would be allowable here to refer to an idealized abstract concept "**the** true revolutionary." This type of construction was common in philosophical texts of the late 19th and early 20th centuries.